# Divide each character/digits from the double to form new integer(through remainder )

Tags: java, arrays, regex

I need to divide every character of this double by 2 and get its remainder `(3.9191070819954144E14)`. Example `3/2=1(remainder)`, `9/2=1(remainder)` until finish and form new value 11... .This is the result I get,`norrrmal 0.1679....Value` not pass

```
  //the value come from rulesfpadouble
 double rulesfpadouble =  3.9191070819954144E14;

 DecimalFormat numberFormatted = new DecimalFormat("#");
 System.out.println("rule : \t" + numberFormatted.format(rulesfpadouble));

 //Start encode the data//

         String[] too = rulefpas.split("/^\\d*\\.?\\d*$/");//Regex split

        double a[] = new double[too.length]; //Makes new int array

        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        a[i] = Double.parseDouble(too[i]); //Converts String to int
        System.out.println("a value"+ a[i]);
        }

       double[] normal = new double[a.length];
          for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++)
          {
           normal[k] = a[k] % 2;
           str = Arrays.toString(normal);
           System.out.println("norrrmal"+str);
         }
```

Comment: Try `System.out.println("norrrmal"+normal);` -> `System.out.println("norrrmal"+str);`. i.e. print the string version of your result that you carefully created.

Comment: why this question down voted ?
he did all his best and he faced problem, this mean we can help him if he tried

Comment: I get the value but the actual answer suppose 110111.. but i get 0.1679..

Comment: What is the value of `rulefpas`

Comment: String rulefpas= Double.toString(rulesfpadouble);....it hold the same value but i change to string before splitting. forgot to copy here

Comment: If your 3rd digit is `1`, How the answer will be like `110....`. It should be like `111...`

Comment: This is not the real code ...the value of rulesfpadouble autogenerate..so the one i count is the latest one..just for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example string you might first remove all that is not a digit using `\D` and replace that with an empty string and split on an empty string to get an array.

Then loop through the array and store the remainder in a new array:

```
double rulesfpadouble = 3.9191070819954144E14;
String[] too = String.valueOf(rulesfpadouble).replaceAll("\\D", "").split(""); 
int[] remainders = new int[too.length];

for (int i = 0; i < too.length; i++){
    remainders[i] = (Integer.parseInt(too[i]) % 2);        
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(remainders));
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/NIW55574)